# Excel vba array transpose size limit

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, size, limit

I have a fairly straightforward sub that loads a 2d array via a series of loops.
 After loading the array with strings, I run a simple filter and load only the wanted columns into a new array of rows.
Afterwards I transpose the array using a generic transpose function posted on this site in another question...

The problem I'm having is my data set is something like:

Array (27, 8000) 
I print this to a sheet ...range(rng) .resize.ubound(Array...
But nothing outputs. I reduce the array to (24,8000) and it works. 
The research I've found gives me a conservative limit of 2^31-1 which is much higher than what I'm messing with. I think I'm running into a limit issue, but it doesn't make sense why. It's excel 2013 on a Windows 7 64 bit Hp desktop from a couple years ago. It shouldn't be a machine limit and excel limit shouldn't be an issue either... I'm flummoxed. If anyone could throw me a bone I'd appreciate it!

Comment: The limit is 65536 (2^16).

Comment: Excel has some issues. Technically if you have excel >2010 and use a newer file format you can have a larger array size than 65536 however some functions have not been recoded to handle the larger arrays and still have an array size 65536 limit so it very much depends upon how you are manipulating the data.