# Array of over 400,000 lines not correctly pasting into excel range?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, error-handling

I have a large macro that categorizes each line of a worksheet and once the array is built, it pastes into a column next to the data.  I cannot figure out why the data is pasting #N/A for the majority of the lines.  The code runs without error, and the categorization works up to the 30k-40k line range, then is #N/A from that point on.  However, the array itself has all the correct values.  So for some reason, when pasting the array into the excel range, its not working properly.

The code is very large, but its basically the last line of code.  I have also attached a screenshot that shows the array has the correct values, it just won't past correctly into the sheet.
[Locals showing the array values and the sheet showing #N/A after running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVeyd.png)

```
Sub categorizeData()
    Dim SearchArray As Variant
    Dim ClassifiedArray As Variant
    Dim results As Variant
    Dim LRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    'Array to count data (starts with zero in every category)
    'To add category, add another zero to array
    ReDim results(0 To 38)
    For i = LBound(results) To UBound(results)
        results(i) = 0
    Next i
    
    'Instantiate variables
    Dim conf As Variant
    Dim negConf As Variant
    Dim helpConfus As Variant
    Dim mentalHealth As Variant
    Dim plans As Variant
    Dim enrollment As Variant
    Dim technical As Variant
    Dim cancel As Variant
    Dim admRelated As Variant
    'New Adds
    Dim financeRel As Variant
    Dim financialAid As Variant
    Dim payments As Variant
    Dim affordability As Variant
    Dim events As Variant
    Dim one As Variant
    Dim two As Variant
    Dim three As Variant
    Dim four As Variant
    Dim five As Variant
    Dim a As Variant
    Dim b As Variant
    Dim c As Variant
    Dim d As Variant
    Dim e As Variant
    '
    Dim Deferral As Variant
    Dim DropOut As Variant
    Dim Faculty As Variant
    Dim Bullying As Variant
    Dim Transfers As Variant
    Dim Deadlines As Variant
    Dim Roommate As Variant
    Dim TeamProject As Variant
    Dim TimeOff As Variant
    Dim JobLoss As Variant
    Dim Donations As Variant
    Dim grateful As Variant
    Dim advRelated As Variant
    Dim graduated As Variant
    Dim counted As Boolean
    Dim exists As Boolean
    Dim received As Long
    Dim existsC As Long
    Dim sent As Long
    
    Cells.Replace What:="=-@", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False _
        , FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Cells.Replace What:="=+@", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False _
        , FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    SearchArray = Range("C1:E" & LRow)
    ReDim ClassifiedArray(1 To LRow)

    ' "like" expressions to catch categories
    ' To add another word, add "*[insert word]*"
    
    cancel = Array("*sto*p*", "*opt out*", "*quit*", "*remove*", "*unsubscribe*", "*cancel*", "*no more*", "*wrong*", "*don't want*", "*take me off*", "*i am not*")
    admRelated = Array("*electronically*", "*sent*", "*transcripts*", "*diploma*", "*dimploma*", "*transcript*", "*apply*", "*application*", "*applied*", "*admissions*", "*financ*", "*admission*", "*deferred*", "*test*", "*reference*", "*placement*")
    financeRel = Array("*funding*", "*loans*", "*expenses*", "*financ*", "* pay*", "*promissory note*", "* fee *", "* fws*", "*fafsa*", "*grant*", "*federal*", "* fa *", "* aid *", "*scholarship*", "* bill*", "*invoice*", "* owe *")
    'Here are the 4 arrays. Just populate them using the keywords you want, following the format of "*[Word]*". The financial keywords are above if you want to use some of those.
    financialAid = Array("*fafsa*")
    payments = Array()
    affordability = Array()
    'Here are certain words that may pertain to certian events, so you can add to the events array when you need.
    'addDrop: help|class|confus|add|drop|availab|open|full|space|close
    'registration: problem|help|when|add|regis|class|full|availab|close|open|confus
    'orientation: lost|confus|event|where|when|full|close|dorm
    'graduation: ceremony|graduat|class of|cap|gown|speech|event
    events = Array()
    one = Array("1")
    two = Array("2")
    three = Array("3")
    four = Array("4")
    five = Array("5")
    a = Array("a")
    b = Array("b")
    c = Array("c")
    d = Array("d")
    e = Array("e")
    grateful = Array("*you're welcome*", "*thank*", "*thanks*", "*thankful*", "*thankyou*", "*thank you*", "*appreciate*", "*your help*", "*life saver*", "*perfect*")
    advRelated = Array("*masters*", "*certificate*", "*dropped*", "*advice*", "*advisor*", "*advising*", "*credit*", "*appointment*", "* course*", "*class*", "*need to*", "*sick*", "*study abroad*", "*internship*", "*transfer*", "*major*", "*module*", "*modules*")
    conf = Array("*good to go*", "*that's fine*", "*will do*", "*all good*", "*sounds good*", "*got it*", "*will do*", "*receipt*", "*requested*", "*done*", "*finished*", "*completed*", "*yes*", "*yeah*", "*yay*", "*yep*", "*yuh*", "*cool*", "*confirmation*", "*yup*", "*great*", "*alright*", "*awesome*", "*ok*", "*for sure*", "*totally*", "*on it*", "*do it*", "*that?s it*")
    negConf = Array("*no*", "*nah*", "*nope*", "*isn?t*", "*sorry*", "*is not*", "*not*")
    helpConfus = Array("*attempted*", "*help*", "*confused*", "*instructions*", "*hold*", "*figur*", "*huh*", "*is there*", "*help*", "*[?]*", "*talk*", "*are you*", "*holds*", "*what*", "*why*")
    mentalHealth = Array("*discouraging*", "*discouraged*", "*feeling good*", "*sad*", "*need to talk*", "*counsel*", "*suicid*", "*death*", "*scar*", "*apprehensive*", "*worr*", "*anxious*", "*sick*")
    plans = Array("*updated*", "*update*", "*defer*", "*plan*", "*why not attending*")
    enrollment = Array("*class*", "*full time*", "*part time*", "*enrollment*", "*enrolled*", "*dual*", "*waitlist*", "*regist*")
    technical = Array("*error*", "*firefox*", "*chrome*", "*browser*", "*portal*", "*access*", "*email*", "*log in*", "*login*", "*logging in*", "*logged in*", "*password*", "*lms*", "*system*", "*user name*", "*locked out*")
    graduated = Array("*conferred*", "*graduated*", "*graduation*", "*class of*", "*retired*")
    Deferral = Array("*deferral*", "*gap year*")
    DropOut = Array("*quit*", "*drop out*")
    Faculty = Array("*faculty*", "*teacher*", "*professor*")
    Bullying = Array("*bully*", "*scared*", "*mean*")
    Transfers = Array("*transfer*", "*leave*")
    Deadlines = Array("*deadline*", "*due*", "*due date*")
    Roommate = Array("*roommate*")
    TeamProject = Array("*team project*", "*group project*")
    TimeOff = Array("*take a break*", "*take a leave*", "*time off*")
    JobLoss = Array("*lost job*", "*unemployed*")
    Donations = Array("*donation*", "*day of giving*", "*alumni day*")


    'Code to iterate through every message and classify
    'To add new category, follow example of one below and change variable names
    For j = LBound(SearchArray) To UBound(SearchArray)
        Dim val As String
        If SearchArray(j, 1) = "received" Or SearchArray(j, 1) = "a--received" Then
            received = received + 1
            SearchArray(j, 3) = LCase(SearchArray(j, 3))
            val = SearchArray(j, 3)
 
             'Opt Out
            counted = False        'Used so one message isn't counted twice
            exists = False          'Used to classify uncategorized messages
            For i = 0 To UBound(cancel)     'Goes through array of "like" expressions
                If val Like cancel(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(0) = results(0) + 1     'Updates Count
                    counted = True          'If found, do not let this expression count again
                    exists = True           'Don't count towards unclassified
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"  'Ensuring it is of type received
                End If
            Next i
            
            'Admissions
            counted = False
            For i = 0 To UBound(admRelated)
                If val Like admRelated(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(1) = results(1) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i

            'Finance
            counted = False
            For i = 0 To UBound(financeRel)
                If val Like financeRel(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(2) = results(2) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'Grateful
            counted = False
            nopeCount = 0
            If val Like "*no thank*" Then
            nopeCount = nopeCount + 1
            End If
            For i = 0 To UBound(grateful)
                If val Like grateful(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(3) = results(3) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            results(3) = results(3) - nopeCount
            
            'Advising
            counted = False
            For i = 0 To UBound(advRelated)
                If val Like advRelated(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(4) = results(4) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i

            'Positive Confirmation
            counted = False
            For i = 0 To UBound(conf)
                If val Like conf(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(5) = results(5) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
                
            'Negative Confirmation
            counted = False
            For i = 0 To UBound(negConf)
                If val Like negConf(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(6) = results(6) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
                
            'Help or Confusion
            counted = False
            For i = 0 To UBound(helpConfus)
                If val Like helpConfus(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(7) = results(7) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
                
            'Mental Health
            counted = False
            For i = 0 To UBound(mentalHealth)
                If val Like mentalHealth(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(8) = results(8) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
                
            'Plans
            counted = False
            For i = 0 To UBound(plans)
                If val Like plans(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(9) = results(9) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'Enrollment
            counted = False
            For i = 0 To UBound(enrollment)
                If val Like enrollment(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(10) = results(10) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
                
            'Technical
            counted = False
            For i = 0 To UBound(technical)
                If val Like technical(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(11) = results(11) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'Graduated
            counted = False
            For i = 0 To UBound(graduated)
                If val Like graduated(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(12) = results(12) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'Financial Aid
            counted = False
            For i = 0 To UBound(financialAid)
                If val Like financialAid(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(13) = results(13) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'Payments
            counted = False
            For i = 0 To UBound(payments)
                If val Like payments(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(14) = results(14) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'Affordability
            For i = 0 To UBound(affordability)
                If val Like affordability(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(15) = results(15) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
                'Events
            For i = 0 To UBound(events)
                If val Like events(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(16) = results(16) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'Deferral
            For i = 0 To UBound(Deferral)
                If val Like Deferral(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(28) = results(28) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'DropOut
            For i = 0 To UBound(DropOut)
                If val Like DropOut(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(29) = results(29) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'Faculty
            For i = 0 To UBound(Faculty)
                If val Like Faculty(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(30) = results(30) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'Bullying
            For i = 0 To UBound(Bullying)
                If val Like Bullying(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(31) = results(31) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'Transfers
            For i = 0 To UBound(Transfers)
                If val Like Transfers(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(32) = results(32) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'Deadlines
            For i = 0 To UBound(Deadlines)
                If val Like Deadlines(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(33) = results(33) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'Roommate
            For i = 0 To UBound(Roommate)
                If val Like Roommate(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(34) = results(34) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'TeamProject
            For i = 0 To UBound(TeamProject)
                If val Like TeamProject(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(35) = results(35) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'TimeOff
            For i = 0 To UBound(TimeOff)
                If val Like TimeOff(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(36) = results(36) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'JobLoss
            For i = 0 To UBound(JobLoss)
                If val Like JobLoss(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(37) = results(37) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'Donations
            For i = 0 To UBound(Donations)
                If val Like Donations(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(38) = results(38) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'a
            For i = 0 To UBound(a)
                If val Like a(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(17) = results(17) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'b
            For i = 0 To UBound(b)
                If val Like b(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(18) = results(18) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'c
            For i = 0 To UBound(c)
                If val Like c(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(19) = results(19) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'd
            For i = 0 To UBound(d)
                If val Like d(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(20) = results(20) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'e
            For i = 0 To UBound(e)
                If val Like e(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(21) = results(21) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'One
            For i = 0 To UBound(one)
                If val Like one(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(22) = results(22) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'Two
            For i = 0 To UBound(two)
                If val Like two(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(23) = results(23) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'Three
            For i = 0 To UBound(three)
                If val Like three(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(24) = results(24) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'Four
            For i = 0 To UBound(four)
                If val Like four(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(25) = results(25) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'Five
            For i = 0 To UBound(five)
                If val Like five(i) And counted = False Then
                    results(26) = results(26) + 1
                    counted = True
                    exists = True
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Classified"
                End If
            Next i
            
            'If you add a category above, make sure to update the number in this as well
            'Checks messages that are not classified and makes them green to be easily visible
            'Makes messages that are not classified to have a type of "a--received" so that they go to the top.
            If exists = False Then
                results(27) = results(27) + 1
            '    Cells(l, 5).Font.ColorIndex = 14
                    ClassifiedArray(j) = "Unclassified"
            End If
            'Cells(l, 5).Font.Bold = True
            
    'Grays out sent messages
            Else
                sent = sent + 1
                ClassifiedArray(j) = "Sent"
            '   Cells(l, 5).Font.ColorIndex = 16
            End If
    Next j
    
    'Prints the results in the table to the right of all of the data
    Cells(2, 19).Font.ColorIndex = 16
    Cells(1, 19).Value = "Received: " + str(received)
    Cells(2, 19).Value = "Sent: " + str(sent)
    Cells(1, 15).Value = "Opt-out: " + CStr(results(0))
    Cells(2, 15).Value = "Admissions related: " + CStr(results(1))
    Cells(3, 15).Value = "Finance related: " + CStr(results(2))
    Cells(4, 15).Value = "Grateful: " + CStr(results(3))
    Cells(5, 15).Value = "Advising: " + CStr(results(4))
    Cells(6, 15).Value = "Positive Confirmation: " + CStr(results(5))
    Cells(7, 15).Value = "Negative Confirmation: " + CStr(results(6))
    Cells(8, 15).Value = "Help/Confusion: " + CStr(results(7))
    Cells(9, 15).Value = "Mental Health: " + CStr(results(8))
    Cells(10, 15).Value = "Plans: " + CStr(results(9))
    Cells(11, 15).Value = "Enrollment: " + CStr(results(10))
    Cells(12, 15).Value = "Technical: " + CStr(results(11))
    Cells(13, 15).Value = "Graduated: " + CStr(results(12))
    Cells(14, 15).Value = "FAFSA: " + CStr(results(13))
    Cells(15, 15).Value = "Payments: " + CStr(results(14))
    Cells(16, 15).Value = "Affordability: " + CStr(results(15))
    Cells(17, 15).Value = "Events: " + CStr(results(17))
    Cells(18, 15).Value = "Deferral: " + CStr(results(28))
    Cells(19, 15).Value = "DropOut: " + CStr(results(29))
    Cells(20, 15).Value = "Faculty: " + CStr(results(30))
    Cells(21, 15).Value = "Bullying: " + CStr(results(31))
    Cells(22, 15).Value = "Transfers: " + CStr(results(32))
    Cells(23, 15).Value = "Deadlines: " + CStr(results(33))
    Cells(24, 15).Value = "Roommate: " + CStr(results(34))
    Cells(25, 15).Value = "TeamProject: " + CStr(results(35))
    Cells(26, 15).Value = "TimeOff: " + CStr(results(36))
    Cells(27, 15).Value = "JobLoss: " + CStr(results(37))
    Cells(28, 15).Value = "Donations: " + CStr(results(38))
    Cells(1, 17).Value = "Polling Answers"
    Cells(2, 17).Value = "A: " + CStr(results(17))
    Cells(3, 17).Value = "B: " + CStr(results(18))
    Cells(4, 17).Value = "C: " + CStr(results(19))
    Cells(5, 17).Value = "D: " + CStr(results(20))
    Cells(6, 17).Value = "E: " + CStr(results(21))
    Cells(7, 17).Value = "One: " + CStr(results(22))
    Cells(8, 17).Value = "Two: " + CStr(results(23))
    Cells(9, 17).Value = "Three: " + CStr(results(24))
    Cells(10, 17).Value = "Four: " + CStr(results(25))
    Cells(11, 17).Value = "Five: " + CStr(results(26))
    Cells(29, 15).Value = "Unclassified: " + CStr(results(27))
    Cells(29, 15).Font.ColorIndex = 14
    Cells(1, 13).Resize(LRow, 1) = Application.Transpose(ClassifiedArray)
    MsgBox "Action completed"
End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.Transpose` has a limit of elements it can handle... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736261/excel-vba-array-transpose-size-limit and others. Use a 2D array and write it directly to the range in question, bypassing `Transpose`.

Comment: Also, rather than a wall of declarations at start, it would be easier to read your code if you declare variables close to their first usage.

Comment: ^^^^^ In general this could use some refactoring. There's too many lines of code in one subroutine that's doing too many things.

Comment: I would recommend considering using the following add-in to help review your code (plus it does plenty more): https://rubberduckvba.com/

Comment: Thank you all very much.  I am sure there was a way to condense the code, but I am just learning VBA so your input has been very helpful.  I changed the ```ReDim ClassifiedArray(1 To LRow)``` to ```ReDim ClassifiedArray(1 To LRow,1 To 1)``` and it works now.